# out of stock's notification mail is not working

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I am using magento 1.8.1 and i am getting error in notification email for out of stock. i am getting mail in this form

```
 Hello Admin.'<br/>Customer'.wants to be notified when the below product is available in our inventory<br/><p>Item Name :</p><p>SKU :</p><p> Search Code :</p><p>Bar Code :</p>
```

where no any detail show regarding product.

when i check in \app\code\local\Adodis\Pincodecheck\controllers

the code is:

```
     $to = "sales@abcd.com";
     $subject = "Product in demand";
    $txt = "Hello Admin.'<br/>Customer'.".$pincode."wants to be notified when the below product is available in our inventory<br/><p>Item Name :".$name."</p><p>SKU :".$sku."</p><p> Search Code :".$scode."</p><p>Bar Code :".$bcode."</p>";


     mail($to,$subject,$txt);
```

can you please tell me what is need to modify in this code to get a proper mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these headers and pass it:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$to = "sales@abcd.com";
     $subject = "Product in demand";
    $txt = "Hello Admin.'<br />Customer'.".$pincode."wants to be notified when the below product is available in our inventory<br /><p>Item Name :".$name."</p><p>SKU :".$sku."</p><p> Search Code :".$scode."</p><p>Bar Code :".$bcode."</p>";


     mail($to,$subject,$txt, $headers);
```